# src files from Xcode give me error: does not name a type in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, openframeworks

someone passed me an openFrameworks project src folder. The project has a class called "rectangle."

Inside the src folder there are *main.h, testApp.cpp, testApp.h, rectangle.cpp, rectangle.h*.
I directly replace the src folder in my empty project, but the project won't compile.

I believe the search directories are right since the class files are also in the src folder.

However CB shows me the "error: Rectangle does not name a type" in testApp.h

```
 Rectangle myRect;
```

I already included the header files in testApp.h (#include "rectangle.h") and have the rectangle.h include ofMain.h

Not sure if I am doing the right way to include a class.

Thanks!

The testApp.h file:

[image]

The rectangle.h file:

[image]

The rectangle cpp:

[image]

file structure:

[image]

Comment: One possibility is that you are not including the rectangle.h you think you are. Maybe there's another rectangle.h on your system getting picked instead. To test this theory put a *deliberate error* in your rectangle.h. One that would cause a compiler error. Then recompile and see if you see the error you introduced. This will test whether the right rectangle.h is getting included. If that doesn't work then post some code.

Comment: still won't work. I added some screenshots! I hope those explain more about my situation. Thanks!!

Comment: 'still won't work' what does that mean? What did you try? Nothing in the screen shots tells me what you're doing wrong. Better to post the actual text of the code however.

Comment: try matching the case of the file and the class - either make the file Upper case or the Class lowercase

Comment: It's always good to get down to a baseline first: Is your EmptyExample compiling and running in order, first? If yes, what happens when you replace the contents with your project, and add the rectangle files?

Answer (score 0):

You don't give enough information so it is all speculation. However, my guess is that the barely visible `ofBa...` is the culprit! If this class happens to have a function called `Rectangle`, this names is found and it clearly isn't a type. Here is the short example you should have posted, demonstrating the problem:

```
class Rectangle
{
};

struct foo
{
    void Rectangle() {}
};

struct bar
    : foo
{
    Rectangle r;
};
```

One fix for the problem is to use `::Rectangle` instead of `Rectangle` as this qualification forces the look-up at global scope.

Comment: I added more detail! please take a look!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try what I proposed? ... and, if so, where is your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) example?